# WatchService: Filter event notification based on filename pattern

Tags: java, watchservice

currently i'm using an if statement to filter out watch event based on file name. if there a way for me to only getting notification from certain files based on filename pattern only?
Thanks

```
 if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE) {
          Path item = (Path) event.context();
          Path dir = (Path) key.watchable();
          if(FilenameUtils.getExtension( item.toFile().getName()) == ".xml")
          System.out.println("ENTRY_CREATE: " + item.toFile().getName());
}
```

Comment: Tell us, please, how is this related to Spring Integration or Spring Boot at all? Looks like you just use `WatchService` directly...

Comment: Hi, I was using WatchService inside of Spring Integration using FileReadingMessageSource. But you get the point this is only related to watchservice, let me remove the spring tag. Thanks

Comment: If you use `FileReadingMessageSource`,. I don't see how could you use `WatchService` with a custom logic like that. The `FileReadingMessageSource` is configured for `WatchEventType.CREATE` by default and can be supplied with `FileListFilter` to filter out files from the watch service events. I'm not sure what else you would need and why to think about a custom logic: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#file-reading

Comment: @ArtemBilan Hi, I tried to filter out with both RegexPatternFileListFilter and SimplePatternFileListFilter but I tried getting events notification form the files i dont want to get notification from. Can you show me how to please

Comment: I'm not fully understand your question. Please, give an example: this is what I want to produce as a message and this I don't want.